# Animating 3d object in R Markdown html with play3d

Tags: r, 3d, r-markdown, rgl

Is it possible insert code into an R markdown chunk to allow [`play3d`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.99.16/topics/play3d) to animate 3d plots in the resulting html? Here is an example markdown:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```    
```{r, webgl = TRUE}
A <- merge(1:100,1:100,by=NULL)
A$z <- 0.5*A$x - 0.5*A$y
plot3d(x=A$x,y=A$y,z=A$z)
play3d(spin3d())
```
````

Knitting the file opens a device window and animates the plane as specified, but the knitting process hangs until the user presses `ESC` when the device has the focus; when this is done knitting resumes and the resulting html file contains only a static 3d plot (i.e. no animation).

Without saving a movie ahead of time, is there a way to animate `plot3d` objects in the markdown html?

Comment: No, but see the WebGL vignette in `rgl` for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`play3d` is purely for controlling the `rgl` display within R.  To control the display in an HTML document it's a little more complicated.  You need code like this:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```    
```{r}
A <- merge(1:100,1:100,by=NULL)
A$z <- 0.5*A$x - 0.5*A$y
plot3d(x=A$x,y=A$y,z=A$z)
fn <- spin3d()
control <- par3dinterpControl(fn, 0, 3, steps = 15)
rglwidget() %>% playwidget(control, step=0.01, loop = TRUE, rate = 0.5)
```
````

This will show a display something like this:

[image: screenshot]

You can click on the buttons to control the spinning.

Comment: This works great, and thanks for the useful reference to the vignette in your comment. For anyone else who is interested, it may be worth exploring the 3d animating capabilities of the magick package.